# code with f = fopen("textfile","a") returns NULL for f in another device but runs perfectly on mine

Tags: c, file, codeblocks, fopen

Hi i have created and run a program in my machine but when i try to run the code in another machine it doesn't run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    char buff[50];
    f = fopen("textfile.txt","r");
    if(f==NULL)
        exit(1);
    printf("Contents before appendiing: ");
    while(fgets(buff,50,f)!=NULL)
        fputs(buff,stdout);
    fclose(f);
    f = fopen("textfile.txt","a");
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nEnter contents to append (type 'exit'to stop): ");
    do{
        fgets(buff,50,stdin);
        if(strcmp(buff,"exit\n")==0)
            break;
        fputs(buff,f);
    }while(f!=NULL);
    fclose(f);
    f = fopen("textfile.txt","r");
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nContents after appendiing: ");
    while(fgets(buff,50,f)!=NULL)
        fputs(buff,stdout);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

The program gives this output in my original machine where it works as it is supposed to be:

```
Contents before appendiing: hello world

Enter contents to append (type 'exit'to stop): hello
exit

Contents after appendiing: hello world
hello

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 10.006 s
Press any key to continue.
```

While it gives this one in my other machine:

```
Contents before appendiing: hello world
Unable to open file
Process returned 1 (0x1)   execution time : 4.452 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I understand this is happening because the value of f became NULL, but why does it happen on one machine and not the other.
I am running windows 10 and using code::blocks IDE on both machines.

Comment: Print the error message represented by `errno` to see the reason why `fopen()` failed.

Comment: Since you could read the file on both machines, you probably don't have write permission to the file on the second machine.

Comment: Aside: the loop control `} while(f!=NULL);` is incorrect, you should control it like this: `while(fgets(buff,50,stdin) != NULL) { ... }`

Comment: @Weather Vane I am pretty new to programming so it would be helpful if you could tell me why `while(f!=NULL);'  is incorrect

Comment: Because that keeps testing if the *output* file was opened successfully, which you already did. The value of `f` won't change during the output writing. The loop should be checking for the end of the *input* file.

Comment: @Barmar Printing the error message gave "Permission denied" as output. How do i get permission to access the file ? Thanks for helping.

Comment: On Linux you use `chmod`. I don't know how to do it on Windows.